# Using base64 to avoid SQL injections?

Tags: sql-injection

It it a good or bad idea if I put a base64 layer over the user input before inserting into SQL? Everything gets encoded (not encrypted) withbase 64 before it reaches SQL queries to stop any SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Can you please explain your idea in more detail?

Comment: If you put userinput eg login data in a database, you can inject sql. My question is, if you save everything with a base64 layer, can you still do sql injection?

Comment: @jojii: please add information which are needed to understand the question by editing the question and not (only) by adding a comment.  Also, I don't seem to be the only one who has trouble to understand your question. I recommend to edit the question and add a  minimal but detailed enough example of what you intent to do and why do you think it will help against SQL injection.

Comment: Base64 is not encryption. It is encoding. To answer (what I think is) your question: converting user input to base64 would encode quotes and other control symbols... but you have to convert the user input back to use it. So in the long run it doesn't help.

Comment: It's no problem to decode it back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use bind variables to avoid SQL injection, such as:

```
UPDATE users SET JOB=?, SALARY=?, BONUS=?, COMM=? where id=someId
```

You then pass user input `JOB`, `SALARY`, `BONUS`, `COMM` as bind parameters.

What you want to do is to encode user input in base64 and then put that into the database as base64? That would mean to query the database, you would have to decode the stuff.

An other option it to encode user input in base64, decode, then store in database. That will give you nothing but overhead and will not prevent SQL injection.

**WARNING**: Storing passwords in `base64` encoding in a database is a crime, do not ever even consider doing that, you might as well store passwords in clear text. Hire a data security expert, you would not want to end up making the headlines on the long list of breached companies! NB: I AM NOT a data security professional by profession.

Assuming that the attacker uses the following:

```
something'; drop table users; ---
```

the base64 encoding of that would be

```
c29tZXRoaW5nJzsgZHJvcCB0YWJsZSB1c2VyczsgLS0t
```

All good so far, however, if you were to query this value, you would have to encode/decode base64 in your query/result set.

For example, assuming you would want to select all rows where `UINPUT` started with *something*, you would do this when the value is not base64 encoded:

```
select USERS.* from USERS where UINPUT like 'something%'
```

and this if it were encoded:

```
select USERS.* from USERS where UINPUT like 'c29tZXRoaW5n%'
```

Where `c29tZXRoaW5n` of course is the base64 encoding for `something`, this is tedious. Worse, base64 encoding has padding for strings that do not have multiples of `3` characters, such as `=`, which means that `something` works, here, but `somethin` (`c29tZXRoaW4=`) does not!

Since base64 encoding cannot have space/quotes, you cannot inject, however, using this is tedious, prepared statements with bind variables is MUCH better.

Comment: Why, if I store the userinput with base64 encryption, sql injection is no longer possible...

Comment: `?` We already `taught you` that base64 IS NOT encryption BUT encoding, very, very, very big difference!!! for the answer to this second question, see @Anders'. Basically, you cannot have a quote or space in base64 encoded string, like this: c29tZXRoaW5nJzsgZHJvcCB0YWJsZSB1c2VyczsgLS0tCg==

Comment: Of course I encrypt the password with a hash. But then I would prefer to encode it with base 64 like every text/string

Comment: If you want to avoid SQL injection, use prepared statements/bind variables -> SQL injection impossible. If you have character set issues, as in, US ASCII database and want to store UTF-8, then, and only then, maybe, base64 makes sense, but that is really the only case where I think it makes sense. `base64` encoding passwords is big No, No, No, good! Consider using a salted hash for passwords if not already!

Comment: Passwords are hashed of course. The base 64 is just for avoiding the injection. That doesn't means that I don't hash the password

Answer (score 9):

This could "work" in a very narrow sense of the word. If you base64 encode all user input that is destined for SQL queries, I can't see how it would be possible to do a SQLi attack since the base64 alphabet doesn't contain many useful characters.

But driving a nail into a piece of wood by repeteadly banging your forehead against it would probably also "work", but it would cause you a lot of unnecesarry suffering. There is a tool for that - it's called a hammer. And there's a tool for preventing SQL injection - it's called prepared statements.